# How to join this data in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql

If I have a table like this:

**`TABLEA`**:

```
id| object | type
1 | greg | person
2 | mary | person
3 | jared | person
4 | kelly | person
5 | melissa | person
6 | william | person
7 | skiing | hobby
8 | biking | hobby
```

**`TABLEB`**:

```
id | husband | wife
1 | greg | mary
2 | jared | kelly
3 | william | kelly
```

**`TABLEC`**:

```
id | female | hobby
1 | mary | skiing
2 | kelly | biking
```

Is there some way I could get a result table of:

**`TABLED`**:

```
id | a | b | link
1 | 1 | 2 | related
2 | 3 | 4 | related
3 | 6 | 4 | related
4 | 1 | 4 | related
5 | 2 | 7 | likes
6 | 4 | 8 | likes
```

Using only MySQL query(/ies)?

- Logic would basically start iterating from TABLE B and all rows of table B.
- The third column is `related` when the table being selected is `TableB`, and is `likes` when the table being processed is TABLE B.

Sample logic would be:

Looking at the first row of `TABLEB` (husband) greg and wife (mary), it looks up from TABLEA to see that greg is at row 1 (id 1) and mary is at row 2 (id 2) and creates a new TableD with the first row being 1 | 2.

Is there a query that can do some join or something that would be able to do this without having to programmatically iterate through all rows of TABLEB, then all rows of TABLEC to produce the desired TABLED?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to `JOIN` the table `tablea` two times with the `tableb`:

- one for `husband` > `object` and another,
- one for `wife`    > `object`.

So that you can get the two ids of the husband and wife in the same row.

The same with `Tablec` with `tablea`. Then use `UNION`(implicit distinct) or `UNION ALL` to union the two result sets.

Something like:

```
SELECT
  (@rownum := @rownum + 1) AS id,
  sub.*
FROM
(
  SELECT 
    ah.id     AS a,
    aw.id     AS b,
    'related' AS link
  FROM tableb       AS b
  INNER JOIN Tablea AS ah ON ah.object = b.husband AND ah.type = 'person'
  INNER JOIN Tablea AS aw ON aw.object = b.wife    AND aw.type = 'person'
  UNION ALL
  SELECT
    a.id  AS a,
    a2.id AS b,
    'hobby'
  FROM tablec       AS c
  INNER JOIN tablea AS a  ON a.object  = c.female 
  INNER JOIN tablea AS a2 ON a2.object = c.hobby AND a2.type = 'hobby'
) AS Sub, (SELECT @rownum := 0) AS t;
```

### [SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/7cc1f/7)

This will give you:

```
| ID | A | B |    LINK |
------------------------
|  1 | 1 | 2 | related |
|  2 | 3 | 4 | related |
|  3 | 6 | 4 | related |
|  4 | 2 | 7 |   hobby |
|  5 | 4 | 8 |   hobby |
```

**Note that:**

- This query will give you only 5 rows, where the expected result set that you are looking for is 6. It is missing the row `4 | 1 | 4 | related`, because there is no entry for those `greg`(id 1) and `keyll` (id 4) in the `tableb`. As you explained in your question.
- The new column `id` is auto incremental id, generated from the result set, it is not selected from the tables.

---

If you need to create a brand new table from this select, use the following syntax:

```
CREATE TABLE Tabled
AS
SELECT ...
... -- the same previous select query
```

and you will have a new table `tabled` having the same structure of this `SELECT`.

[**Like in this updated fiddle.**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/3bfee/1)

Answer (score 0):

```
create table tabled (
  id int auto_increment,
  a varchar(10),
  b varchar(10),
  link varchar(10));

insert into tabled (a, b, link)
select a1.id a, a2.id b, 'related' link
from tablea a1
join tableb b on a1.object = b.husband and a1.type = 'person'
join tablea a2 on a2.object = b.wife and a2.type = 'person'
union all
select a1.id a, a2.id b, 'likes' link
from tablea a1
join tablec c on a1.object = c.female and a1.type = 'person'
join tablea a2 on a2.object = c.hobby and a2.type = 'hobby';
```